# TextMate/Macfusion combo for mounting projects over SSH

Tags: ssh, textmate, macfuse

Here is my workflow: I use Macfusion to mount a server over SSH, and then edit the root directory of the project in TextMate (using `mate /Volumes/server/projectdir`). I have a plug in installed that disables refreshing on refresh. This works ALMOST perfectly--the only thing I have problems with is "Find in Project": it's REALLY slow. Has anyone run into this problem before and been able to find any solutions? Currently I go to terminal when I have to do a search, but it would be great to be able to do it in TextMate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Find in Project is slow no matter what. You probably want something like [AckMate](http://github.com/protocool/AckMate)